# Book SciFi/Romance: Female author travels back in time to WW2 and flies in a B-17 bomber

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a SciFi/Romance book, where a female author - living with her (great-) grandmother(?) - is writing a biography about the crew of a B-17 bomber a relative (grandfather?) flew in during WW2.  The bomber was shot down over occupied France.  Among the papers, she finds a picture of the crew, plus a woman she can't quite make out.

I believe she is contacted by an old man - a survivor of the crew or a friend - and somehow sent back in time.  She befriends the crew and joins a mission (as a journalist?) - and the photo is taken of her and the crew.

> The plane gets shot down, and she and one of the crew (possibly more) travels through the French countryside with Germans after them.  I believe they're hidden by locals for a while.
>
>  I believe they do a raid against a German base and sabotage it.
>
>  After the raid, they're almost caught, but time-travel at the last moment.  The man is lost, but the woman returns to her own time - where she finds her grandfather alive and several new relatives.
>
>  Later, the man somehow catches up with her, which starts a relationship.

I believe the book starts out with her as a TV-reporter and/or documentary-maker who's done lots of crazy stuff to see "what scares...".  Her latest was training as an elite-soldier (Navy SEAL?) and jumping out of a plane - which made her qualified for what happened later.

She changes the destiny of a crew-member to die a hero's death, rather than die a failure years later. I think he's a bit of a Casanova and tried to date her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Out of Time](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/40564477-out-of-time)* (2005) by Pauline Baird Jones.

[image: Cover of *Out of Time*: blond woman about to kiss a taller, dark-haired pilot]

> She's a modern woman. He's a blast from the past. Can their love survive the test of time... and war?Adventure reporter Melanie "Mel" Morton tackles current events, not historical retellings. But that all changes when a WWII veteran tracks her down and seeks her help in saving her gold-star grandfather's life... by traveling back in time.
>
> For Mel, the stakes keep rising until she finds herself on her grandfather's fateful final mission. Shot down behind enemy lines, Mel and Jack Hamilton, the now-young and handsome pilot, must navigate the occupied French countryside and their generational differences. With her grandfather's life and her future on the line, Mel and Jack can't afford the distraction of their undeniable chemistry. Failure to complete their mission could get them killed, or worse, change the course of history.

Found with a search for *romance novel female author time travel grandfather bomber*

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to be the one.  I tried "sci-fi book time-travel woman flies in bomber during ww2" - but admittedly remembered more details as I wrote the question...

Comment: It's often like that. :) I've had more than a few that I started writing the question and, in the process of recounting details, recalled the right search string.